# how to start create json parser in xcode (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, storyboard

I want create json parser that read many data in way json. (data include images and text and etc) but dont know with json library and method create json parser. please more explain about this issue?

Comment: You probably don't need to create JSon parser, Instead you can use ALREADY created JSon parser to parse any JSon data/format.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5.. After reading this tutorial you get clear idea about json parsin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSJSONSerialization that is built in iOS sdk. Small example:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:      NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
}
}
```

Or if you want to go with some open source parser, use  [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/). SBJSON is really good and a lotta people use it. I would advise you to go with NSJSONSerialization in the first and later explore other things.